# dataGridView change cell datasource and type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

After I click a particular row and I click a `button`, I want to change the `cell` type from default type (`DataGridViewTextBoxCell`) to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` and to change that cell data source to a list.

Somehow I encountered an unexplained behavior, In one line it works and shows the `ComboBox`, in other, it just enters to edit mode.

My code looks something like this:

```
 private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    dataGridView.BeginEdit(true);

    var selectedRow = CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    var selectedColumn = CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    var cellName = dataGridView[0, _selectedCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    var dict = GetDict(cellName);

    if (dict != null)
    {
       var comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
       {
           DataSource = dict.Keys.ToList()
       }
       dataGridView[1, selectedRow] = comboBoxCell;
       dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[selectedColumn];
    }
    dataGridView.BeginEdit(false);
}
```

**Update:** It seems only after the `event` `CellBeginEdit` is fired, which is caused by pressing other `cell` it updates, But then it takes like 3-4 click for the `ComboBox` to open.

Comment: Same Code is working super fine in my case.

Comment: You Should try same code in `CellClick` Event.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/WaseemAhmadNaeem/a38044667648cb431bfae76c9591dc42/

Comment: Check My Code is Last Comment

Comment: I added your code with dataGridView.BeginEdit(false) at the same place and it worked!, if you want to post a reply I'll accept it as an answer. @WaseemAhmadNaeem

Comment: Answer Posted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code. You should override `CellClick` Event or Call You Method There. This code is written in `CellClick` Event, Don't get confused with Name

```
//This Code is written in CellClick Event not in CellContentClick (Don'tconfuse with signature)
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
            var selectedRow = (sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            var selectedColumn = (sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            var comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
            {

            };
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
            dataGridView1[selectedColumn, selectedRow] = comboBoxCell;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[selectedColumn];
           dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
        }
```